# Searching for executable files

Tags: bash

Is there a way to search and delete all executables files within folder if there is no extension?

e.g  Let's suppose I have 4 files with .ubu extension and the following bash does the job I'm asking for:

```
rm *.ubu
```

e.g_2 Now let's suppose I have 4 but there is no extension at all, something like:

test test_2 test_3 (`chmod +x` on them)

How do I delete those files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we're talking about files with executable bit set, then `find` command has `-executable` test, and a `-delete` action.

```
find /DIR/EC/TORY -type f -executable -delete
```

or

```
find /DIR/EC/TORY -type f -executable -exec rm -f {} \;
```

should do the trick.

To specifically delete all executable files in your home directory (not in sub-directories) and ask you whether you want to delete each file you can do something like

```
find ~ -type f -executable -maxdepth 0 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

from `man find`:

> ```
>    -exec command ;
>           Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
>           arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
>           an  argument  consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}'
>           is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere
>           it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
>           where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both  of  these
>           constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or quoted to
>           protect them from expansion by the shell.  See the EXAMPLES sec‐
>           tion for examples of the use of the -exec option.  The specified
>           command is run once for each matched file.  The command is  exe‐
>           cuted  in  the starting directory.   There are unavoidable secu‐
>           rity problems surrounding use of the -exec  action;  you  should
>           use the -execdir option instead.
>
>    -exec command {} +
>           This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
>           the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
>           each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invoca‐
>           tions of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
>           matched  files.   The command line is built in much the same way
>           that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of  `{}'
>           is  allowed  within the command.  The command is executed in the
>           starting directory.
> ```

Comment: I have 2 files / executables in my home directory, call them what you want but don't append an extension, how can I delete these files using a simple bash command  ?

Comment: Thank you Sergey, can you explain a little the second command ?
    rm -rf {} \; 
what does this mean ?

Comment: If you only have 2 files and you know their names, why don't you just do `rm test test_2 test_3`? Or delete them in Nautilus? I thought the question was "how do I generally delete any executable files in a directory"

Comment: @pyn: the second command is "find anything of type *file* with executable bit set in directory /DIR/EC/TORY and below and for each file found execute `rm -f` command passing it the full path to the file."

Comment: 2 files was just an example, you are right with the question.

If I understood well {} means the full path to that directory ? Thank you for your patience and understanding (I know, my english is awfull ).

Comment: @pyn: also note that in the second command I used `rm -f`, not `rm -rf` (where `-r` stands for "recursive" and `-f` is "force"). Since we only look for files, the effect would be the same, but using `-r` with `-f` is a bit scary because it can delete whole directories with their contents without any prompt. At any rate, it is advisable to test the command first by running it without `-exec rm -f {} \;` part - it will just print the names of the files it found to the terminal.

Comment: I understand the risk of using rm -rf but the part I dont fully understand is: {} \ ; ( I suppose semicolon means end of the line like in programming ).

Comment: @pyn: I've updated my answer

Comment: I see, so the {} means the name of the file(s) found by the find.

Answer (score 0):

To find files (or directories!) without a dot, use the extended file matching pattern

```
!(*.*)
```

You need `shopt -s extglob` -- I think that option is on by default in interactive shells.

To delete executable files in bash

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
for file in !(*.*); do
    [[ -f $file && -x $file ]] && echo rm "$file"
    # -f -> true if it's a file
    # -x -> true if it's executable
done
```

Answer (score -2):

A binary file will have the executable bit marked.

So you can write a simple bash script which checks if the executable bit is set, and if so delete the file.